# Is it possible to control the visibility and depth of objects inside the volume?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, shaders, volumetrics

Is there a way to make the cube inside a foggy volume appear as if there is no volume at all?

That is, it did not lose its contrast and was displayed normally and not vaguely.

Is it possible to somehow control the depth of the impact of volume on objects without compositing?

[image]

Comment: honestly i don't understand the question. you want to add volume but it should appear as if there were no volume at all? isn't that contradictory? maybe explain a bit better what you want?

Comment: Imagine a smoky scene in which the objects are close to each other, but you need one to stand out more clearly and not lose as much contrast as the other objects because of the smoke, how do you do this without changing the position of the objects and the smoke that fills the whole scene? @Chris

Comment: maybe add an image how it should look like?

Comment: hello, maybe use the compositor?